# Outlook 2007 very slow since yesterday

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I use Outlook 2007 since over a year perfectly fast.

Since I woke up this morning its horrible: every time you click a folder it needs ~20 seconds to load the emails for the folder (doesn't madder if there are 5 emails in it or 5000).

I don't know if it has st. to do with it, but yesterday 1) I have my .pst-file again to my backup HDD 2) I download all new windows 7 updates.

Any ideas?

Comment: IMAP, POP3 or Exchange?

Comment: Could you add the date of "yesterday", please? (It appears that date is Wednesday, December 15, 2010.) Otherwise, readers will have to try to figure out the day you asked this question, which may or may not be possible in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [some chatting on the Patch Management mailing list about KB2412171 causing slowdowns](http://marc.info/?l=patchmanagement&m=129243551409442&w=2). You may want to look into that.

Comment: Wow! I disabled the AddIn and have 90% of the normal speed back.

Comment: +1 Running Win 7-64 with Office 2007 and the same fault. Uninstalling KB2412171 cured it for me.